# NHibernate - Unique index with WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using `Fluent NHibernate` and I'm trying to create a table with a unique column that ignores null values. After long research I got to a conclusion that the only possible way to do so is to create unique index with WHERE clause, like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyIndex on MyTable (MyColumn)
WHERE MyColumn IS NOT NULL
```

Right now I'm running this script manually when I need it. Is there any way to map the column in `Fluent` so it checks automatically?

I'm using Sql Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

you can mention the unique column in `mapping class` : check the following example

```
public class AccountsMap : ClassMap<Accounts>
{
    public AccountsMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(x => x.Username).Unique().Nullable(); //Here the username column is unique 
        Map(x => x.Password);            
    }
}
```

Comment: this would allow exactly one row with a null value. The next insert with Username=NULL will throw an exception...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a check on the column that the value is unique unless it is null. If it is null, null can occur multiple times right?

Then no, I cannot find any option to set this.

The schema generation in nhibernate simply does not support it!

`Map(x => x.MyColumn).Unique().Nullable();` would create an unique index for this column, and the column would be nullable, though you cannot insert multiple rows with null value...